# Running a springboot api using Tomcat and getting slow query error

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am running a springboot api on Apache Tomcat. The api is being consumed by a mobile app, but the app tends to be slow once alot of users login and start using the app, when a few users are logged in, the app seems okay, but as more users login, it starts becoming slow.
On checking the Tomcat log file I get this error occuring frequently

> a sql query INFO: [SLOW QUERY] Slow query (exceeded 2000 ms, duration: 316 ms) as prepared: then another query

It keeps occurring throughout the log file till almost the end of the log document.

We enabled caching and compression for Tomcat, we increase the server memory, we also increase JVM heapstack. The application is still running slow once lots of users login.